# How to call stored procedure from pyspark

Tags: python, sql-server, pyspark

I am connecting to SQL Server using `jdbc` in `pyspark`. For converting table to dataframe I am using the following query.

```
query="SELECT * FROM tablename"

df=sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:sqlserver://{servername};database={dbname};user={uid};password={pwd}", dbtable=query).load()
```

Now I need to connect to a stored procedure and using the same JDBC. I found some answers with pyodbc, but I want it with JDBC only due to some issues in my `SQL Server` and pyspark configuration.

```
Stored procedure = exec name "a","b"
```

How can I achieve this?